# How to Convert XAML to c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm using accordion control.

```
<dxa:AccordionControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="dxa:AccordionItem">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOverHeader" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="black"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</dxa:AccordionControl.Resources>
```

But I don't use it anymore ↑
because I changed the contents of the item dynamically.

```
Setter setter = new Setter();
           Style style2 = new Style();

           style2.TargetType = new AccordionItem().GetType();
           setter.Property = AccordionItem.ForegroundProperty;
           setter.Value = Brushes.Red;
           style2.Setters.Add(setter);

           ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
           resourceDictionary.Add(style2.TargetType, style2);

          //Trigger trigger = new Trigger();
          //trigger.Property = AccordionItem.IsMouseOverHeaderProperty;
          //trigger.Value = true;


           accordionControlHistoryMenu.Resources = resourceDictionary;
```

How Can I express it this xamlcode convert xaml to C# source?

Comment: change `new AccordionItem().GetType()` to `typeof(AccordionItem)` - no need to instantiate object

Comment: Oh, there's that method Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to store the style in a ResourceDictionary, just assign it directly:

```
Xaml:
<dxa:AccordionControl.Resources x:Name="myControl">

Code:
myControl.Style = style2;
```

While this answers your question, it's almost never the correct way to do this. Your styles should be [binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0) to dynamic data that your [view model layer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern) is creating.

Comment: "styles should be binding to dynamic data that your view model layer is creating" - using Style with Triggers (not DataTriggers) is *perfectly* acceptable to change visual state of UI element. why should view model care about `IsMouseOverHeader` state? (it is readonly DP most likely and therefore cannot be used as binding Target)

Comment: @ASh i think you misunderstood my answer (or maybe I wasn't clear enough). Styles and Triggers are components of System.Windows, so of course they should never be declared or used in the view model. OP is trying to implement dynamic styles, so what I was getting at is that he should declare them in XAML and then use data binding to either 1) set property values directly, or 2) indirectly via DataTriggers etc.